# Where is Index Agent Admin Console

Tags: indexing, documentum, emc

I'd like to find out where can I access the Index Agent Admin Console in EMC Documentum.

I've being looking at a number of posts online, none of them explains exactly how I can access it. One of the posts suggested:

```
1. Login to Index Agent Admin console through http://localhost:(index agent port     no.)/IndexAgent(no.)/login.jsp
```

I have no idea what is the index agent port no. they talking about and how I can find it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, the port number is set by the user when the Index Agent is installed.  It also depends on if you are talking about FAST or xPlore.

I believe the default port is `9081` for the FAST index agents using your url above.

For xPlore, the default configuration url is `http://<HOST_NAME>:9200/IndexAgent`.

You may want to take a look here if that doesn't help you: https://community.emc.com/community/support/documentum

Comment: Thanks @unicron, we use FAST. how do I find out what the port number initially set when IndexAgent was installed?

Comment: @dale I don't have an environment I can check at the moment, but you can probably look at what ports are in use by using `netstat`.  You can also look at the service information in the Windows Services control panel and see if there is port information in the service startup parameters or in a configuration file nearby to the service executable.

Comment: For some reason when I typed 9081 and it worked. Not sure why it didn't work last time... Thanks @unicron, much appreciated!

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.  Maybe the service wasn't started when you tried before.